# Javascript to read Text File to Array without a Webserver or external libraries local on Windows PC

Tags: javascript, file

I have an HTML file with JavaScript that I am running without any Webserver/host so I am just opening the file in a browser local to my windows PC.  In that HTML file I would like to be able to read a text file in the same folder as the html file.  That file will contain data in rows and columns separated with tabs.  i.e

1     a
2     b
3     c

I want to keep this as simple as possible so all I have to do is share the HTML and Text file to others so the can open it up local to their computer without any webserver/host and without having to also copy of external libraries like node.js or jquery.

I have searched and tested everything I can find but either I need to reference an external library or I have to run it in a webserver or I need to click a button to load the file through the browser, none of what I want.

Does native JavaScript support the function to read a text file and save it to an array? If so, any code direction would be great.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

`XMLHttpRequest()` exists in native JavaScript, I think it will help you.

You also can send a request to the file. Or use library: `axios.js` because when you use `XMLHttpRequest()` you lose many time to write code which just get content from file, with axios I got file content with one line: `axios.get('file.txt').then(result => console.log(result.data));

To connect Axios: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>`

You can read official documentation about `axios.js` and `XMLHttpRequest()` in the net.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest() only works within a web server host and not stand alone so that is out but I will give axios.js a try.

Comment: Looks like axios.js is Web server http based library so without a web host I dont think it will work either.

Comment: Yeah.. Sorry. Then I think you should use a server to open any file, `Apache` for example. You can download `Denwer`, it also supports `PHP, mySQL`.